# Flagging based specific ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm searching for an Excel formula that can flag specif weekly ranges, I have the following sample data with the desired output on columns 'Flag 1' and 'Flag 2':

[[image: Sample data]

So for 'Flag 1' column, I need to put '1' after 8 weeks of every new month based on 'Week' or 'Month' columns. For 'Flag 2', I need to put '1' after every two weeks from flags with values '1' in 'Flag 1' column.

This is related to a much complex task, in case you wonder what is the purpose of this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a fancier way, but this should do the job, you just need to create a 'helper' table.  I've only included the necessary columns.

The grey section is the helper table and could be on the same or a different sheet.

- Column 'E' is just the 1st of each month. You can either just create a series or put 1st Jan in E2, then `=EOMONTH(E2,0)+1` in E3 and drag down.
- Column 'F' has the formula `=(E2+6-WEEKDAY(E2))+(7*7)`.  It takes the value in E2, works out the 1st Friday, then adds 7 weeks (you said 8, but you're including the 1st week of the month).
- Column 'G' is just a dummy value for what comes next
- In 'B2' put the formula `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$F$2:$G$13,2,0),0)`.  This is looking up the helper table to see if the week can be found.  If it finds, it, it adds 1, otherwise (ie IFERROR true), it adds 0.
- 'C2' just has `=IF(B1=1,1,0)` so is just adding a 1 if the row above is 1.

[image: example table]

**Additional question - Flag 2**

To make Flag 2 = 1 5 weeks post Flag 1, use an extra helper column.

- Column 'G' formula is just `=F2+(7*5)`
- Flag 2 formula is now `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$G$2:$H$13,2,0),0)`
- Flag 1 may also need updating (should do it automatically if you insert column 'G', but if not, it should now be `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$F$2:$H$13,3,0),0)`

[image: Example]

Comment: this is perfect, thanks a lot! Just one more question, for Flag 2 column, how about if I want to add the flag (number 1) after every 5 weeks from the first flag in Flag 1 column (from 19.2.2021 in this case)?

Comment: @Peter_07 I just added some extra content to my answer.  Can you mark the answer as correct please :)

Comment: Excellent!! Many thanks and appreciate your help.